# I am getting a parser error message

Tags: php, parsing

I am getting a parser error whenever I try to execute a program.

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected '.' in /var/www/html/spywgc/adm/ctshell/getproduct/getproduct.php on line 9
```

This is the code

```
$select_url= " select product_id from sp_url where url like '%.$url.%'";
```

$url is a string and I want to retrieve it from database to assign it to $select_url.

Comment: What is the value of `$url`? Could you post the lines above and below this line too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant to have the dots in there, but you can do any of the following:

- `$select_url= "select product_id from sp_url where url like '%.{$url}.%'";`
- `$select_url= "select product_id from sp_url where url like '%." . $url . ".%'";`

Comment: @vincy: Have a look at @Marc B's answer. This error is an indication that he is right. I asked you to post more of your code, but you didn't. It would have been so much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3):

The line you posted is syntactically correct. The real error is that somewhere BEFORE that line, you have a string with an unterminated `'`.

```
$somevar = 'blah blah    <--missing ' here
... blah blah blah ...
$select_url = "...... '%   <---string closes here
```

So you're ending up with

```
$somevar = 'big long string select product_id .... ' % .
```

% is the modulo operator, which would normally be fine, but then it's followed by a . which isn't valid.

```
"string modulo concatenate"
```

and as others have said, your string is internally incorrect. You're using a double-quoted string, so there's no need for the attempt at concatenation within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have presented above I am assuming you want to do something like this

```
   /* Assuming you have a database connection already */
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT product_id FROM sp_url WHERE url LIKE '%".$url."%'";
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $select_url = $row['product_id'];
```

edit: you may want to escape $url as well
mysql_real_escape_string($url)

Answer (score 0):

Dots arent even needed, you could end with something like that:

```
$select_url= "SELECT product_id FROM sp_url WHERE url LIKE '%$url%'";
```

And then make your mysql_query with this string.

Comment: Could you add a Sample value of the string?